# How can I monitor SSH or HTTPS activity on Juniper SRX 240 firewall?

Tags: juniper, juniper-srx

In Junos is there any way I can monitor SSH or HTTPS login activity though logs? I would like to receive alerts if there are any changes made in the current config.

Comment: There are tools which can retrieve configurations periodically (or after changes) and report any changes, that may be a more useful approach. Software recommendations are off-topic here though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Junos you can both of these requirements are captured in the default `messages` log file.

```
show log messages
```

You can also create a dedicated log file for this if you want:

```
set system syslog file ACTIVITY auth any
set system syslog file ACTIVITY change-log any
```

Comment: Is there any way I can store those logs on remote server or Desktop ?

Comment: https://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB16502&actp=METADATA

Comment: Yes - change `file ACTIVITY` to `host 1.2.3.4`